# Scrapy run two crawlers sequentially where the second crawler takes input from the first

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I am running into a problem that's been posted on here several times. That is, I'm trying to run two crawler process in one script and getting a `ReactorNotRestartable` error.

The answers I have seen provide ways to run spiders concurrently or sequentially but without any parameters being passed around in the middle.
I need to run one spider, do some work with the output, and then run a second spider with a parameter set depending on the output from the first spider. Here is my pseudocode:

```
def do_shallow_scrape():
    results = []

    def crawler_results(signal, sender, item, response, spider):
        results.append(item)

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal=signals.item_passed)

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl('list')
    process.start()
    return results


def do_details_scrape(ids):
    results = []

    def crawler_results(signal, sender, item, response, spider):
        results.append(item)

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal=signals.item_passed)

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl('details', ids=ids)
    process.start()
    return results


def coordinate_scrape():
    shallow_results = do_shallow_scrape()
    ids = some_script(shallow_results)
    details = do_details_scrape(ids)
```

Thanks in advance for you help!